# chrome drawImage only at integer coordinate

Tags: google-chrome, html5-canvas, coordinates, rounding, drawimage

This bug report with the same name explains well the problem that I encountered with. There are some tests, that shows the problem.

[chrome drawImage only at integer coordinate](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=86676)

Here I've created a fiddle with the smaller code to show exactly the difference.

```
var x = 0,
    y = 0;
cv = document.getElementById("my-canvas");
ctx = cv.getContext("2d");

ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';

var im = new Image();
im.src = "http://dummyimage.com/32x32/ffffff/000000.png?text=png";

setInterval(function () {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cv.width, cv.height);

    // Uncomment one of these
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, 32, 32);
    //    ctx.fillRect(Math.round(x), Math.round(y), 32, 32); // Chrome
    //    ctx.fillRect(Math.floor(x), Math.floor(y), 32, 32);
    //    ctx.fillRect(Math.ceil(x), Math.ceil(y), 32, 32);

    ctx.drawImage(im, x, y + 40);

    x += 0.1;
    y += 0.07;

}, 1000 / 20);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/esasha/22p5qtpn/)

What is going on is that chrome roundes the coordinates using `Math.round()`. If you uncomment the line with `Math.round()`, you will see both squares behave the same in chrome. While in FF both squares behave smoothly.

I would like to get the smooth behavior in chrome. And if it is really a bug, I would like to fill the bug report since the old one was closed.

I've tested how does the `imageSmoothingEnabled` help and it seems, that it does not make any effect in chrome.

Here is another fiddle that shows if the `imageSmoothingEnabled` helps.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/esasha/34gb8z54/)

Comment: Smoothing is enabled by default. What exactly is your question?

Comment: Smoothing does not help. It has some effect in FF, but no effect at all in chrome.

Comment: Canvas has a half-pixel resolution. When you increment x & y by less than a half-pixel, the browser must determine which half-pixel boundary to snap to. Therefore, your smaller increments are not used during the layout of rendering (except when == half or whole pixel). To get uniform movement your resulting x/y should always specify a half-pixel boundary. BTW, better still if the x/y of fills always specifies an integer pixel coordinate and the x/y of strokes always specifies a half-pixel coordinate. That's because strokes are always drawn half inside & half outside the specified coordinate

Comment: The problem is in drawImage function only. I know how the coordinates work when drawing strokes but it is different in images and it is different in FF and in Chrome and it is the problem. If there is no solution, may be it is a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rotate the context of the canvas with a very small angle:

```
ctx.rotate(0.0000000001);
```

This seems to solve the problem (at least on PC).

Comment: This does nothing in current chrome